# How should unexpected browser termination during an AJAX request be handled by a Java web app in production?

Tags: java, ajax, web-applications

I have a very standard web application that handles AJAX requests from a standard Javascript client running in the browser.

Unsurprisingly, when the browser is closed while the server is in the middle of reading data from it, an exception is thrown. In production this is a not an uncommon thing.

There are some great suggestions on here about preventing the user from closing their browser while waiting for a response, but my question is concerned with the unavoidable losses of connection. ie. user's PC loses power, network cable unplugged etc.

Would industry best practices for Java web apps be to suppress this exception? Or should it be logged? The stack trace in my system is entirely within third party libraries (library starts reading, but then throws exception before passing this data to my code) Is it even feasible for me to suppress this if I wanted to? I feel like having these unavoidable exceptions in production is not appropriate.

Comment: It seems like as long as the request is handled as a single atomic transaction, then it doesn't really matter. Long as the exception results in a rollback anyway, that seems appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would remove "AJAX" from the question all together, this is not AJAX specific.

Also the wording "having these exceptions in production is not appropriate" should be changed, there is no way to not have these exceptions, you probably meant "logging these exceptions".

I would be careful with suppressing any exceptions coming out of response handling. I would at least log the exception message. If suppressing, you need to be 100% sure that the exceptions you suppressed are caused by the failure of the requesting end. In Java, it's not feasible to determine the source of an exception, and none of the web frameworks I know would ever throw special subclass of an exception that would indicate that the exception is specific to to that failure. The obvious problem with suppressing exceptions - is suppressing the ones that matter, and having unnecessary problems evaluating root causes for other issues.

You probably should post another question about a particular library/framework you are using, asking whether for that framework, ignoring exceptions past specific point would be safe.

Note that some web frameworks would have hard separation between *reading of the data*, *processing the data*, *writing the data*. For those, typically, the *writing of the data* stage can be abandoned for exception checks, but I've seen cases where exceptions, and even IO exceptions would be thrown, and would not be related to the other side of the request.

Then there are other web frameworks that follow streaming or asynchronous model, where it would be quite hard to know which part has caused an exception.

Comment: I would generally agree with all of these points. You are correct that I am mainly concerned with how the exceptions should be logged. Although most of these exceptions are likely due to the normal and unavoidable behaviour of users closing their browsers, we

Comment: can't really know for sure (it could be a network issue on the server side). I'll have to think a bit more about this in general. StackOverflow apparently didn't let me finish my comment after taking more than 5min.